# 'Provided that' followed by 'no sooner'

Tags: conditionals

I came across this odd-phrased (to my ear at least) sentence in a text I'm proofreading, would appreciate your opinion:

"... the settlement agreement may be executed at any stage of the bankruptcy proceedings, **provided that** **no sooner than** the list of creditors is approved"

Is it OK? I would have used a ‘dummy’ subject or rephrased it completely.

Comment: Is that the end of the sentence? It would be grammatical if the actual subject and predicate of the subordinate clause followed, like so: “provided that no sooner than the list of creditors is approved X happens”. That would just mean, “provided that X happens no sooner than the list of creditors is approved”. If there is nothing more in the sentence, it is ungrammatical, and _provided that_ is unnecessarily unwieldy. You could simplify it to “… at any stage of the bankruptcy proceedings, but not before the list of creditors is approved”.

Comment: That is the end of the sentence :)
It's a formal legal text, hence the wordiness))) Thank you!

Comment: If it is a legal document, you could go with, “… at any stage of the bankruptcy proceedings subsequent to the approval of the list of creditors”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not grammatical as is, and I suspect that either some words got left out or someone attempted to modify it from one phrase to another, but accidentally left in part of the original. A possible correction might be "... provided that this occurs no sooner than ...".

Comment: That's what I figured, thank you! It's just that the text has already been proofread by a native speaker (which I'm not), this is why I wanted to be sure before pointing out a grammatical mistake :)
Thanks again!